# Java Lambda Expression to C# Translation

Tags: java, c#, .net, itext

I am currently trying to convert this piece of Java, which contains Lambda Expressions (.stream(), .filter(), collect() methods) code to C# LINQ code:

Java Code:

```
        Map<Rectangle, PdfStream> highlightStreams = page.getAnnotations()
            .stream()
            .filter((a) -> (PdfName.Stamp.equals(a.getSubtype()) || PdfName.FreeText.equals(a.getSubtype())) && a.getNormalAppearanceObject().isStream())
            .collect(
                    Collectors.toMap(
                            a -> a.getRectangle().toRectangle(),
                            a -> (PdfStream) a.getNormalAppearanceObject()
                    ));
    page.getAnnotations().forEach(page::removeAnnotation);
```

Here is the C# that I have so far. Some of the API classes are from iText7. I would like some help on it if possible please on how this can be translated to C#.

C# Code:

```
            Dictionary<Rectangle, PdfStream> highlightStreams = page.GetAnnotations()
            .Where(
                (a) => (PdfName.Stamp.Equals(a.GetSubtype()) || PdfName.FreeText.Equals(a.GetSubtype()))
                       && a.GetNormalAppearanceObject().IsStream())
            .ToDictionary(a => a.GetRectangle().ToRectangle(), 
                a => (PdfStream) a.GetNormalAppearanceObject());

        foreach (var pdfAnnotation in page.GetAnnotations())
        {
            page.RemoveAnnotation(pdfAnnotation);
        }
```

Comment: And what is the problem you have with the code you have already?

Comment: The problem is that the output is a broken PDF Document. Therefore, I am assuming that this LINQ code that I wrote with C# is not equivalent to the Java code. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: My suggestion would be to take the same PDF with both pieces of code, and then compare what the resulting Dictionary/Map contains between Java and C#.

Comment: I am currently doing that, I just wanted to see if anyone had any experience with translating Java lambda expressions (.stream(), .filter(), collect() methods) to C#

Comment: Essentially the only thing you do to the document here is removing annotations after collecting appearances of stamp and free text annotations. Is your pdf broken in respect to any of these? (The only real difference i see at first glance is the way you remove annotations, and in both variants you manipulate a collection while iterating over it, something that may cause trouble depending on the underlying collection. )